# How do I test a REST client?

Tags: java, rest

I have a REST client in Java that is ready to connect to a REST server, send a specific request and get a response back. However, the actual REST server is not available during development time (it is hosted by a 3rd party and only available in the isolated local net of the target machine) and we still want to test connectivity and interaction with the server.

Can you point me to a product or technology that in the first place lets me quickly create a fake REST server (or at least mock it) according to the specification of the REST call parameters? I did some research on the web but haven't had a "yes, this is it!" moment yet.

Comment: do you know the "coding to interfaces" way of working?

Comment: Just use this URL as Rest API
https://openweathermap.org/current OR https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use any rest mocking framework to achieve this. As per my experience
Wiremock is the best framework for RES API Mocking.

http://wiremock.org/

Answer (score 0):

For client testing, I would recommend a tool like SOAP UI or Postman.  But for mocking the REST service itself, I would actually recommend just creating some dummy endpoints in your Java web application and using that.  At each endpoint you could do something hard code a simple response, in JSON, XML, or whatever would make sense with your service.  Then, when you finally come to actual development, you will already have a functioning framework for your REST service.  You would just need to fill in the missing pieces.

This makes sense because you are going to need to setup REST support in your Java code anyway, and the amount of effort to just add stubs should be minimal.  This approach is also attractive from the point of view that it avoids any potential surprises from switching from a mock REST service to the actual one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mockwebserver library by square](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver). It's pretty simple to use and do exactly what you attempt to do.

Little usage sample:

```
MockWebServer server = new MockWebServer();
server.enqueue(new MockResponse().setBody("hello world"));
server.start();
```